# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection constructor does not accept SqlConnection, but it should

Tags: c#, .net

so the problems is that i receive an error when passing SqlConnection class to ServerConnection class. the error says: 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.IRenewableToken' 
but [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.-ctor?view=sql-smo-160#Microsoft_SqlServer_Management_Common_ServerConnection__ctor_Microsoft_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_) it says it can, and in the visual studio says it has that overload but it wont accept it and wont build the project.

I should also mention that when i try to assign the object directly, Visual Studio gets unresponsive and its framerate is like 0.5/s.like this:
ServerConnection servConn = new ServerConnection(){SqlConnectionObject = conn};

this is the whole  code block:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        string stringCon = @"DefaultConnection";
        sfd.Filter = "Database backup files (*.bak)|*.bak";
        sfd.Title = "Create Database Backup";
        sfd.FileName = DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMMyyyy") + ".bak";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            SqlConnectionInfo conn = new SqlConnectionInfo(stringCon);
           
                ServerConnection servConn = new ServerConnection();
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            conn.Open();
            servConn.Connect();
            try
            {
                Server serverdb = new Server(servConn);
                Backup backupdb = new Backup() { Action = BackupActionType.Database, Database = "whdb" };
                backupdb.Devices.AddDevice(sfd.FileName, DeviceType.File);
                backupdb.Initialize = true;
                backupdb.Incremental = false;
                backupdb.SqlBackupAsync(serverdb);
                conn.Close();
                Storyboard sb = Resources["sbHideAnimation"] as Storyboard;
                StatusLable.Content = @"اطلاعات صادر شد.";
                sb.Begin(StatusLable);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: you there are two different SqlClient components? one is System.Data..SqlClient and the other one is Microsoft.Data.SqlClient... which one are you using?

Comment: turns out the wrong one. thank u. this is the right one:Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Comment: answer the question and i will accept. @JonathanAlfaro

Comment: i didn't think that 2 different classes with similar name spaces and exact same constructor and NAME would exist but as it turns out....

Comment: awesome. i am glad you could fix your issue. i posted an answer in case other people run in to the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different sets of classes for SqlClient.

There are two components

```
System.Data.SqlClient
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```

So you have to make sure to use the correct using statement.

Answer (score -2):

The error is coming due to System.data.sqlclient. if you use the other one i.e, microsoft.data.sqlclient, this error can be resolved

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide more information than the previous answer, I think you should read [the help center for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and especially [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Reasons to delete answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)